# HTML table with varying-height rows?

Tags: html, html-table, row, row-height

I want an HTML table which has rows of different heights, like so:

```
row 1: 1 CB   2 CB   3 CB
row 2  3/15   3/20   3/25
row 3: 4 CB   5 CB   6 CB
row 4: 3/30   4/4    4/9
etc
```

Rows 1, 3, etc are normal font; rows 2, 4, etc small font. (CB=check box).

Neither setting the row height with  or  in row 2 has any effect.

Since I am producing the smaller font with, e g,

```
<small>3/15</small>,
```

it looks as if the height of a cell is taken to be the height of the font before the effect of the , and therefore the cells in row 2 will have the normal font height, and the "height=" will have no effect when I specify a smaller height.

How can I achieve the effect I am looking for: alternate "normal" and "small" row heights?

Comment: I assume your table is standard `<table>`. Try using `<div>` based table instead. Otherwise you'll have to try rowspan and small rows.

Comment: Yes, it's `<table>`. As I noted in response to Jason, rowspan won't work. Can you explain what you mean by a `<div>` based table?

Comment: Use `<div>`s instead of table cells `<td>` and then `float:left` these. The divs can be then wrapped in another `<div>` functioning as a table row or even table body. Wrapping `<div>` can have a constant width and each of the cell `<div>`s can have any height you want. Read these to better understand it: [Use CSS display:table for Layout](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout) and [USING CSS “DISPLAY: TABLE-CELL” FOR COLUMNS](http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add multiple rows to your table and then use the `rowspan` attribute to vertically merge the rows and therefore make them look bigger.

Comment: That wouldn't work, because the smallest row I can achieve now is too large for the "small" rows.